# Ionic 3: ng-change doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a input field where a user can input his address and get auto-suggestions:

```
 <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Adresse:</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" ng-model="autocomplete.query" ng-change="updateSearch()"></ion-input>
```

My class has a update method where i want to do something, but unfortunately he doesn't get into it.

```
updateSearch()
  {
    console.log('aaa');
    if (this.autocomplete.query == '') {
      this.autocompleteItems = [];
      return;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of ionic are you using exactly?

Comment: I am using version 3.12.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ng-model` and `ng-change` were used in Angular 1.

With Ionic >= 2, you can use `ngModel` and `ionChange`.

```html
<ion-input
  type="text"
  [(ngModel)]="autocomplete.query"
  (ionChange)="updateSearch()">
</ion-input>
```

The parentheses signify that data binding is from the template to the component, the square brackets, component to the template. When both are present, it is a two way data binding.

For more info on template syntax, look at the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

Comment: Thx, I really appreciate your help

Comment: if element is not ion type? like <select> or non ionic elements then (change)="checkCities()" worked? or both of them worked?